# Better to use getline or cin to populate an array from input file?

Tags: c++, fstream

My problem could be with the index or my syntax here. I'm trying to populate two
arrays `names[]` and `shares[]` from an input file.

One half of the program, manual entry, works fine. Every attempt at the fstream half
has printed an empty output table with `-1.#IND` for the percentage of each
shareholder.

I have tried `cin >> name >> share`, `getline(shareFile, name)`,   `while(shareFile >> name >> share){ ... names[i] = name; shares[i] = share;`, but 
I don't know how use getline the right way I think so I'm working with the first. Like I said,
I don't know if it's a problem with my index or the code here.

This is the function that (I believe) is the problem, but maybe it's just not passing things the right way.

```
void getFileInputs(string names[], int shares[], int size)
{
    string file;
    string name;
    int share = 0;
    bool isOpen = true;
    ifstream shareFile("inputfile.txt");

    cout << "*----------------------------------*\n"
        << "*     Input From File:             *\n"
        << "*----------------------------------*\n";
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file (.txt): ";
    cin >> file;
    cout << "\n";

    shareFile.open("inputfile.txt");

    if(file == "inputfile.txt" || file == "inputfile")
    {
        int i = 0;
        do{

        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                shareFile >> names[i] >> shares[i];
            }

        if(shareFile.eof())
        {
            isOpen = false;
        }
    }while(isOpen == true && shareFile >> name >> share);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unrecognized file name. \n" << endl;
        isOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the input file looks like?

Comment: @R Sahu: My sample input looks like  "name1 share1 (linebreak) name2 share2 (linebreak)..." etc. I don't know how to format comments, but the (linebreak)s are not in the actual file. The assignment just says that the program must take input from the user or an input file. Since there are no examples of the input file, I assume it would only have names and shares since it must have a function taking only names[arrSize] and shares[arrSize] as parameters.

Comment: Please add the sample input file as part of your post.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is the following line of code:

```
shareFile.open("inputfile.txt");
```

A few lines above, when you constructed the `shareFile` object, you opened it with a file name but did not close it. Calling `open()` on an already opened file stream sets an error in the file stream's error mask. As such, any attempt of performing input will fail until the error is cleared from the stream.

Moreover, since `file` is the name of the file, I'm assuming you meant to open it with that. If so, the above should be changed to:

```
std::ifstream shareFile; // default-construct; no file is opened yet
// ...
shareFile.open(file.c_str()); // open it with the value of user-input
```

Another problem is with the looping and how you're assigning the values from the file to the array. Firstly, you shouldn't be using a `do {} while()` but rather a `for()` loop. Also, if `shareFile` hits the end of the stream, then the loop will terminate; thus there's no reason to use a boolean `isOpen` variable:

```
for (int i = 0; shareFile >> name >> share; ++i)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now once the values are placed into both `name` and `share` successfully, you can assign them to the values in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; shareFile >> name >> share; ++i)
{
    names[i] = name; shares[i] = share;
}
```